# JavaFX: Title of program in OS dockbar (Ubuntu 19.10 for example)

Tags: java, javafx, x11

Today I faced the following problem:

I set title for primaryStage using method `setTitle()`. This title is displayed correctly in the window, but when I hover cursor on program icon in OS dockbar I see just path to main program class (see screenshot below). How I can fix it?

[Title in program window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM6AY.png) and [title in OS dockbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6EKc.png). And I use this code:

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        this.stage = stage;
        instance = this;
        // App initialization
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(SlimeBot.class.getClassLoader().getResource("fxml/Main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        stage.setTitle("SlimeBot - Панель управления");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

Trying set title using field in `java.awt.Toolkit`:

````
    @Getter
    private static SlimeBot instance;

    static {
        try {
            Toolkit xToolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            java.lang.reflect.Field awtAppClassNameField = xToolkit.getClass().getDeclaredField("awtAppClassName");
            awtAppClassNameField.setAccessible(true);
            awtAppClassNameField.set(xToolkit, "SlimeBot - Панель управления");
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Getter
    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        this.stage = stage;
        instance = this;
        // App initialization
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(SlimeBot.class.getClassLoader().getResource("fxml/Main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        stage.setTitle("SlimeBot - Панель управления");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

}```
````

Comment: Could you include that code in your question as text, please?

Comment: Okey, see above.

Comment: Please, help me :(

Comment: I think the dockbar looks for a title in the app's WM_CLASS X11 property. This blog post is pretty old, but I think it might lead you in the right direction: http://web.archive.org/web/20160310121729/http://elliotth.blogspot.com/2007/02/fixing-wmclass-for-your-java.html